# Easy Question on Induced Subgraphs.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I was reading through my lecture notes and something was unclear to me, on the topic of induced subgraphs.

Say we have a graph with vertices V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6 with edge set {12,13,14,25,26,35,36,45,46} ... It helps to draw a diagram to picture it.

We are asked to find the induced subgraph(s) for V' = {V1,V2,V3,V4}

I'm wondering is it just the one main graph i.e. the graph with all 4 vertices and the edges 12,13,14 that equals 'the' induced graph, or, is there 3 smaller induced subgraphs with one of them (for example) containing vertices 1,2,3 and containing edges 12,13.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: The former: it’s the graph with vertices $v_1,v_2,v_3$, $v_4$ and edge from $v_1$ to each of $v_2,v_3$, and $v_4$. The induced subgraph determined by a set of vertices has those vertices and all of the edges of the original graph that connect them.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that "induced subgraph" is an operation that associates a definite subgraph with each subset of the vertices of a given graph. By definition, the induced subgraph on $V'$ has $V'$ as its vertex set and has all the edges in the given  graph that connect vertices in $V'$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory. The smaller graph in your example would be the induced subgraph on the proper subset $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ of your $V'$. (Personally, I think the alternative name "full subgraph" is clearer and more memorable than "induced subgraph".)